# Greatest power of 2 less than N?

Tags: notation

Really quick question here:

What sort of formal notation could I use to denote the largest power of $2$ less than $N \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Where does $N$ belongs to ?

Comment: It's an integer.

Comment: **Hint:** $\log_2$ and the floor function will be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Probably ugly, but by definition what you're looking for is $\lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor$.

Comment: Simpler than I thought!  Thanks.

Comment: This would discuss the exponent.  $2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3,\dots$ has exponents $0,1,2,3,\dots$.  Meanwhile, often the sequence $1,2,4,8,16,\dots$ is often referred to as the sequence of powers of two.  If he wishes for $8$ instead of $3$ for the answer when $N=9$, then you will need to raise two to the power of $\lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor$.  Additional modifications might be necessary if the OP wants *strictly less than* instead of less than or equal.

Comment: Yup.  That's an easy fix.